# Is it possible to make a "double arrow" with css3 content technique?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Im looking for a way to recreate [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kta5.png) with CSS only.

[image]

I know about the triangle technique and I also know how to add a border to it, but unfortunately I don't know any way to recreate this button (without adding additional wrappers or using images).

The buttons I need this style on are `<input["submit"]>` and ordinary `<a>`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With one element, you could do it using gradients and skewed pseudo-elements for a link:

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/qGonl)

(you could actually do it using just gradients, but then a hover action won't be triggered  on hover on the arrow shape itself, but on hover on the rectangular element containing it)

**HTML**:

```
<a class='boo' href='#'>click me</a>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.boo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(60deg, dodgerblue 50%, transparent 50%) 100% 0, 
    linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 50%, dodgerblue 50%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 1em, dodgerblue 1em);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1em 50%, 1em 50%, 100% 100%;
}
.boo:before, .boo:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -.2em;
  width: .5em; height: 50%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  content: '';
}
.boo:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
.boo:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

### **EDIT**:

If your background is a solid color, not an image or a gradient, you could do it in a much simpler way, without using gradients (which means that this second method also has the advantage of working in IE9).

## [demo #2](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/LErmB)

```
.boo {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  background: lightblue;
}
.boo:before, .boo:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -.3em;
  width: .5em; height: 50%;
  box-shadow: -.2em 0 0 white;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.boo:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
.boo:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome @Ana, but can you explain why on earth it's not working as expected on the [input-submit and the button elements](http://cssdesk.com/uuQQ9)?

Comment: It shouldn't work on `input` elements (that's why I said for the link in the answer). Input elements are not supposed to have pseudo-elements. As for the button, its `display` is not really  `inline-block` for some reason, even though it was set to be so.

Comment: Will accept it as answer, even though it's not working on the buttons. At least I learned, that buttons have strange display behaviour.

Comment: @Ana - Was looking for something else but landed over here and just loved it. Thanks Ana. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a background image. Create a transparent png containing the arrow.

You would need two elements, the outer would contain the background image, the inner would contain the text, and a background color which is the same as the one on the arrow. Alternatively, you could use a second background image instead of a background color, for example if your button is not just a flat color.

The trick is to align the box containing the text with the background image.

If your arrow is 20px tall, your inner box could be e.g. 16px plus 2px padding on each side (search for *box model* if you would like to understand this better).

The outer element can have a right-margin set to the approximate width of the arrow image.

I hope this makes sense. The general technique is called [sliding doors](http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors). I suggest reading the entire article if you have the time.

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned in my question, I don't want to use images, since I have a lot of different type of buttons with this style with different heights/colors and backgrounds.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't read your question carefully, I guess.
No, it cannot be done simply with css. Even if you have a suitable font where the ">" character would look like this, you couldn't create the pointy part before it.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with just CSS, see my answer.