# Css double arrow

Tags: html, css, svg

Example of what i want to do right:

[image]

I'm trying to create an arrow more like a double arrow. My aim is to have one class for it but I have tried what I know and it's not working.

If anyone can direct me to right way it will be great

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background:black;
}
.arrow1{  
  left:0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 37.5px 0 37.5px 75px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7mfquq2y/

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a "double arrow" with css3 content technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937166/is-it-possible-to-make-a-double-arrow-with-css3-content-technique)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider pseudo element and rotation like this :

```css
.arrow1 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow1:before,
.arrow1:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.6);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -30px;
  top: 40px;
}

.arrow1:after {
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, applying initial `border` property values to *pseudo-elements*, as demonstrated in the code snippet embedded below.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background:black;
}
.arrow {
  height: 95px;
  position: relative; /* required */
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 37.5px 0 37.5px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.7);
}
.arrow:after {  
  bottom: 0;
}
.arrow:before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mfquq2y/2/)